# Midnight values not included in SUM (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am currently working on a SQL job with a sum function which will sum some price values during the day. I was able to implement the sumfunction with success but currently have issues with midnight values.

**Table layout:**

```
Hour                  | price | sum function
------------------------------------
'2014-07-07 06:00:00' | 0     | NULL

'2014-07-07 07:00:00' | 0     | NULL

'2014-07-07 08:00:00' | 1000  | NULL

'2014-07-07 09:00:00' | 1200  | NULL

'2014-07-07 10:00:00' | 1300  | NULL

'2014-07-07 11:00:00' | 700   | NULL

'2014-07-07 12:00:00' | 800   | NULL

'2014-07-07 13:00:00' | 2000  | 5000

'2014-07-07 14:00:00' | 3500  | NULL

'2014-07-07 15:00:00' | 2500  | NULL

'2014-07-07 16:00:00' | 1000  | 13000

'2014-07-07 17:00:00' | 500   | NULL
```

**Challenge:**

The problem exist when the hour, from the table above, meets midnight. The thing is at 01 a clock (the preceeding day) I am interested in having a sum of the previous day from 06-00 hours in a similar manner as shown in the table above during the day. My current sumfunction works well with 06-23 but returns 0 if the range is 06-00. I have been trying alot of options but simply cannot get it to work. I was hoping that one could pinpoint the weekness in my function.

**Code**
So I start by calling this method inside a select:

```
Case When DATEPART(HOUR,t.Hour) = 1 THEN a.sumfunction ELSE NULL END as sumfunction
```

The function it self looks like this:

`OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t2.Hour) BETWEEN 6 AND 23 THEN abs(t2.Price) 
        ELSE 0 END) sumfunction 
FROM dbo.Values t2
where    t2.Hour >= dateadd(hh,5,t.Hour - 1) AND t2.Hour <= dateadd(hh,-1,t.Hour)
)a`

The statement `BETWEEN 6 AND 23` gives the correct sum from 06 to 23 hours, but changeing this to the interval `BETWEEN 6 AND 0` will return a 0. I have been working a lot with the `WHERE`clause but cannot get this thing to work.

I hope you have any ideas.

Thanks!

(MS SQL 2008)

Comment: You could add another condition OR DATEPART(...) = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just subtract one hour and do the comparison within a single day.  I find it easier to  work with `datetime + int` rather than `dateadd()` for this type of operation:

```
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t2.Hour - 1.0/24) BETWEEN 5 AND 23
                 THEN abs(t2.Price)
                 ELSE 0
            END) sumfunction 
 FROM dbo.Values t2
)
```

I am totally unclear as to the purpose of the `where` clause, because your question only mentions one table.  However, you can probably apply the same logic to that.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for `BETWEEN 6 AND 0` returns nothing is simple - from MSDN ([Midnight values not included in SUM (MS SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778566/midnight-values-not-included-in-sum-ms-sql)):

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.

since it can't be greater than 6 and at the same time smaller than 0 it is a contradiction.

instead you could use something like

```
x BETWEEN 6 AND 23 OR x == 0
```

this will take into account also midnight.